# Обработка массивов в php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой вложенный массив:

```
Array
(
    [source] => Array
        (
            [0] => YandexDirect
            [1] => Google Ads
        )

    [utm] => Array
        (
            [0] => yandex/cpc
            [1] => google/cpc
        )

    [budget] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
            [1] => 600
        )

)
```

Как его обработать, чтобы на выходе получить два таких:

```
Array
(
[0] => YandexDirect
[1] => yandex/cpc
[2] => 500
)


Array
(
[0] => Google Ads
[1] => google/cpc
[2] => 600
)
```

Т.е. берутся все нулевые ключи и создается из них новый массив,  потом ключи с индексом 1 и из них создается массив и тд.  Также могут быть ключи с индексом 2, 3 и тд.

Comment: Надо просто названия полей в форме изменить. Или `array_map` с колбеком `null`.

Comment: @u_mulder, что то я не понял вашей мысли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array2 = array();
    
$i = 0;
foreach($array['source'] as $item) {
    $array2[] = array(
            $item,
            $array['utm'][$i],
            $array['budget'][$i]
        );
    
    $i++;
} // где $array - это ваш массив с входными данными
```

Comment: спасибо, получилось

Comment: @aliasst, установите ответ как правильный.